# How to change this function (of a userscript) so that it doesn't cause "unsafeWindow.$ is not a function" in browser console

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

There's this userscript [Twitter profile retweets hider](https://github.com/jerone/UserScripts/blob/master/Twitter_profile_retweets_hider/Twitter_profile_retweets_hider.user.js) *(it hides retweets on Twitter profiles)*

Running it in greasemonkey (3.0 in FF36) causes (in Browser Console):

```
TypeError: unsafeWindow.$ is not a function                   Twitter_pr:115:2
```

That's caused because of the changes [to greasemonkey since v2.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/versions/2.0), reflecting those to the Firefox (since v30) Add-on SDK:

> Greasemonkey Version 2.0 Released June 17, 2014 
>   **Backwards incompatible** changes:
>   - For stability, reliability, and security the privileged sandbox has been updated to match the new [changes to unsafeWindow for the Add-on SDK](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/).
>   **In order to write values to unsafeWindow you will need to use the new methods** `cloneInto()`, `exportFunction()`, and/or `createObjectIn()`.
>   ...

The function which contains the `unsafeWindow` command is:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    addMenuItem();
    unsafeWindow.$(document).on("uiPageChanged", function() {
        addMenuItem();
    });
}, 1);
```

I've already reported it to it's developer in GitHub, and the reason why I ask for your help, is that he's said that he no longer uses this userscript, so, he's either open for a pull request, or else he'll deprecate it.

I've tried a lot (with my limited javascript knowledge) to properly convert the forementioned function using either of `cloneInto()`, `exportFunction()`, and/or `createObjectIn()` (based on the instructions/examples on my 3rd link),
but without any success.

---

**Edit**: what I've tried so far based on Brock Adams comments:

- changed `unsafeWindow.$(document)...` to `window.$(document)...`
  It causes `TypeError: window.$ is not a function` in browser console
- changed `unsafeWindow.$(document)...` to `jQuery(document)...`
  It causes `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: From a *very* quick scan, it looks like you can just change the `unsafeWindow.$(document)...` to `window.$(document)...` that's the whole point of `@grant none` mode.

Comment: I've just tried it (changing line 115 to `$(document).on("uiPageChanged", function() {`) but it gives `ReferenceError: $ is not defined Twitter_pr:115:2`

Comment: I don't use Twitter, but I just checked and `$` ***is*** defined.  Check from the console. Also try `jQuery` instead of `$`.  And you need to use `window.$`, most likely, in the script.

Comment: You're right: adding the key `@require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js` and changing line 115 to `jQuery(document).on("uiPageChanged", function() {` fixes these errors that were popping in Browser Console. Thank you! But, where to add `window.$` in the script?

Comment: Delete the `@require` line and change [line 117](https://github.com/jerone/UserScripts/blob/master/Twitter_profile_retweets_hider/Twitter_profile_retweets_hider.user.js#L117) to `window.$(document).on("uiPageChanged", function() {` .   Make no other changes to that script, for now.

Comment: This causes `TypeError: window.$ is not a function` in Browser Console.

Comment: Huh.  I guess I'd have to try that script myself. Ain't gonna do that; am going offline. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: Hi, author of mentioned userscript here :) With latest GM 3.1 I'm not getting above error anymore and the script works. Does it for you?

Comment: Greetings, I'm really glad you take part in this! I've updated GM to 3.1 but unfortunately the script doesn't work; it shows "TypeError: unsafeWindow.$ is not a function" in browser console, as in my question. I even tried it in a clean Firefox (36.0.3) profile, to make sure.

Comment: And you are running the script in GreaseMonkey, not Scriptish nor TamperMonkey?

Comment: Yes, in Greasemonkey 3.1 (using win8.1 x64). I'm using the v2 of the script, from [here](https://github.com/jerone/UserScripts/tree/master/Twitter_profile_retweets_hider)

Comment: Am not seeing any errors; probably something wrong on my end. Will try Monday at work if I have time, unless someone else finds a solution :)

Comment: Corresponding GH issue: https://github.com/jerone/UserScripts/issues/36

Comment: The script works ok now (using FF38.0.5 with GM 3.2).